# some tests fail on maven while in Junit all passes

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit

I have switched my project to run with Spring .
All tests are running on JUNIT and passes . however on MAVEN some tests only a few fails .

I found that if I am using

```
   <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.9</version>
      <configuration>
        <forkMode>pertest</forkMode>
        <argLine>-Xverify:none</argLine>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

All working ,BUT ! tests is running 45 minutes when before it was running 9 minutes

```
I had tried to use this - > 

<plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.9</version>
      <configuration>
        <forkMode>never</forkMode>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Indeed the tests was finished in 8 minutes but some tests fails.
I am wondering what can be change in order to get it working one test is related to UTF-8 , one for Database.

I am wondering what needed to be change ? is it class Path some How if then how?

any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: It can happen when your unit tests depend on a specific order of execution of tests (ie: your tests are not isolated). Make sure your tests don't need the result of another test.

Comment: Your **unit tests are no unit tests**. They are **integration tests** cause you are using a database so order is important. Apart from that using the `forkMode pertest` and your tests are running and using `forkMode never` exactly shows that your tests are coupled and **NOT** isolated and this is the root cause of your problem. Fix you tests (integration-tests).

Comment: Thanks ! but also could it possible to what jars are in the class path . ? i have issue with one jar that does something . and on pretest it is running great . . how can I change the class path to add it ?